# Replace en Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, macros, microsoft-office, microsoft

Que tal buenos días a todos.
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto dentro de Microsoft Excel, con VBA.

Tengo un form que traspasa la información de un archivo de excel a otro, busco hacer una validación que al momento del traspaso me quite "mm" y deje únicamente los números.

[image: Imagen de apoyo]

Esta imagen corresponde al archivo donde se pegó la información, es decir, en este momento, debería salir la información ya sin "mm".

Por favor espero puedan ayudarme.
Cualquier apoyo es bien recibido, buen día y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mejor momento para quitar los "mm" es a la hora de traspasar los datos del form a la nueva tabla.

Por ejemplo, para tu campo "**TH (mm) MAX**". Suponemos que el campo del formulario donde se introduce ese dato se llama txt_th_max y que tu hoja donde pegas los datos se llama datos:

```
Sheet("DATOS").Range("E" & fila) = Replace(txt_th_max,"mm","")
```

**fila** será tú primera fila en blanco donde vas a insertar ese dato.

Y así con el resto de campos donde quieres eliminar "mm".